# Universal conversion of types

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting, type-conversion

Assuming I have a table Entities with the columns **Value** and **Type** as varchar(strings) in a database, how would I go around to loading these values in C# and converting to the type specified in the table? I was intending to save the getType result for the Type value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the `value.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName` in the `Type` column and then use `Type.GetType(asmQualfName)` to get the type back when loading from the db. After that you can just use `Activator.CreateInstance` to get an object of the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

How do you read from your database?
Are you using ADO.NET, or are you using any kind of OR Mapper such as EF or NHibernate? In the case of OR Mapping you could build a strongly typed object which could define the types... the OR mapper itself is responsible for the casting.

Comment: I use ADO.NET and I've never heard of OR Mapping, any example you could link to?

Comment: Or the Entity Framework which ships with the .NET FX http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Looking for something more generic to avoid specific Data classes such as that example, seems extremely useful for other stuff I'm working on, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx) Method for sample code (which is very similar to ur case) see MSDN Sample linked above.

Answer (score 0):

When you're not using any OR mapper, I would prefer to build a simple class and serialize the instance of that type into xml and store in in a xml column within the databse.

```
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

    public class MySettings
    {
    public String Setting1 { get; set; }
    public int Setting2 { get; set; }

    public String ToXml()
    {
        string settingsXml;
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MySettings));
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, this);
            stream.Position = 0;
            using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                settingsXml = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        return settingsXml;
    }

    public static MySettings FromXml(string xml)
    {
        MySettings settings = null;
        using(MemoryStream stream  = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xml)))
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (MySettings));
            settings = (MySettings) xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
        return settings;
    }
}
```